# MVC3/Razor: cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to convert an MVC2 site to MVC3 using RazorViewEngine.

I used [this tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx) to upgrade my project and the [Telerik converter tool](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter) to convert my .aspx views to Razor.  The Telerik tool put an `@inherits` line at the top of my layouts (inherting from ViewMasterPage).

When I tried to run a page that used one of these layouts, I got the error:

> ...cshtml.Execute(): no suitable method found to override

I removed the `@inherits` tag and it started to work for my home page.  However, I continued to get this error for another page using the same layout.  And now, after moving some things around to deal with an Areas issue, I'm back to getting this error for all my pages (the ones I can get to, anyway).

I have tried closing Visual Studio, deleting temporary files, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out - the following section needs to be in the `web.config` for razor - I had it in the `web.configs` in the `Views` directories, but not in the `root` `web.config`:

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: That config section is technically correct, but you don't need it in your root web.config.  Keep it in ~/Views/Web.config, but just make sure your pageBaseType = "System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage", instead of "System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage".  I just resolved this same error in my application with that minor change.

Comment: @MikeWyatt I'm dealing with this same issue now, and just tried your suggestion, but I get the following error: System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage is not allowed here because it does not extend System.Web.UI.Page.    Any idea what I can do? thanks!

Comment: @dizzwave: I saw that message too, but it was just a warning.  It didn't seem to cause any problems for me, though.  Are you getting a build failure or an error when you run your site?

Comment: @MikeWyatt Yeah, it's actually throwing a ConfigurationException. This is on a site that I converted from MVC 2 to 3, and I'm converting partial views to Razor, one by one. So.. a lot of things going on that could be wrong. :)  Tx for your help!

Comment: @MikeWyatt fabulous addition to this answer. Thank you. We had ours in our area config, but not in the main Views config during a MVC3 > 5 conversion.

Answer (score 5):

There could be a few things going on here. Make sure you are following these guidelines

- you don't have `@inherits` directives in your views. unless you are using a custom view page base class they are unnecessary. For strongly-typed views you should use the `@model` directive to specify the model type. For weekly-typed views you don't need anything.
- don't mix razor views with aspx master pages (or aspx pages with razor layouts), as they don't work together easily. This includes checking all of your action methods where you have code like `return View("ViewName", "MasterName")` since that might also cause conflicting templatign technologies to be used.

Comment: Thanks - I have no @inherits directives and I am using @model directives.  All master pages converted to layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have a backup of your MVC2 project I would try using the tool Microsoft released on MSDN for this. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx) link for more information. Also Scott Guthrie wrote something about it in his blog posts when MVC3 was released, you can read the article [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx).

I'm afraid I can't give you an direct solution to this. But sounds like an bug or problem in the conversion software from telerik you used.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is actually the tool I used. I then used the Telerik tool to convert aspx views to razor.  I will update my post.

Comment: @sydneyos. Can you post an code example of how your CSHTML file looking now?