# List all Membership users into razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-membership

i'm using Razor with MVC3 in my project. I use membership to handle user registration and i want to diplay all my users into a `table` .

here's my Action:

```
 public ActionResult ListProfile()
    {
        //ProfileInfoCollection profiles = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);
        //return View(profiles);
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        return View(users);
    }
```

My View :

```
 @inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MembershipUserCollection>
 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "Documents";
 }

<h2>Liste des documents</h2>
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <th>Nom
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (MembershipUser item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h4>
                @item.UserName

            </h4>
        </td>


    </tr>
}

</table>
```

But i get an error :  `CS0115: 'ASP._Page_Views_AccountProfile_listProfile_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override`

Comment: That looks fine, what's the issue? I'd suggest putting a breakpoint on the var users = Membership.GetAllUsers(); to see what gets filled there and make sure you are getting your users properly.

Comment: Sorry i just update my post with the error

Comment: It is a problem in web.config. Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808640/mvc3-razor-cshtml-execute-no-suitable-method-found-to-override

Comment: i saw this post before but the solution was in the comment... thanks any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to change the basetype to `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`instead of `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` because razor configuration is under `~/Views/Web.config`

Here is the view :

```
  @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<MembershipUserCollection>
  @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Documents";
  }

  <h2>Liste des documents</h2>
  <table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
  <th>Nom
  </th>
  </tr>

  @foreach (MembershipUser item in Model)
  {
  <tr>
    <td>
        <h4>
            @item.UserName

        </h4>
    </td>


</tr>
}

</table>
```